# Why are many nodes missing in my animations in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a portfolio with three.js, and I have made animation sets that I have set to play after an event. This code worked before, but now no matter what I do, I get the same series of warnings, and my code doesn't run at all.
`THREE.PropertyBinding: No target node found for track: LowerBone.position. index-e8a71580.js:3581 THREE.PropertyBinding: No target node found for track: LowerBone.quaternion. index-e8a71580.js:3581 THREE.PropertyBinding: No target node found for track: LowerBone.scale. index-e8a71580.js:3581`
This error series repeats for every single bone in the armature and the actual mesh itself (if your confused, the model is a character that is supposed to be me that I added an armature to). but the mesh doesn't get the scale error. Here's the relevant code:

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <style>
            canvas#Rendered {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
            }
            body {
                background-color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Main.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

function windowWidth() {
    return window.innerWidth / 2;
}

var phaseone, phasetwo = false;

let mixer, mixer1, mixer2, mixer3/*, mixer4*/;
let intro, afkone, trans, afktwo;

const clock = new THREE.Clock();
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, windowWidth() / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var model;
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load( 'untitled.gltf', gltf => {

    model = gltf.asset;

    scene.add( gltf.scene );

    console.log( gltf.animations );

    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model );
    intro = mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[2], model ).setLoop(THREE.LoopRepeat);
    console.log( intro );
    mixer1 = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model );
    afkone = mixer1.clipAction( gltf.animations[0], model ).setLoop(THREE.LoopRepeat);
    console.log( afkone );
    mixer2 = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model );
    trans = mixer2.clipAction( gltf.animations[3], model ).setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce);
    console.log( trans );
    mixer3 = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model );
    afktwo = mixer3.clipAction( gltf.animations[1], model ).setLoop(THREE.LoopRepeat);
    console.log( afktwo );
    intro.play();

}, undefined, function ( error ) { console.error( error ); } );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( windowWidth(), window.innerHeight );
renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
renderer.domElement.id = "Rendered";
renderer.domElement.width = windowWidth();
renderer.domElement.style.left = windowWidth() + "px";
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

camera.position.z = 10;

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
ambientLight.intensity = 4;
scene.add( ambientLight );

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    const delta = clock.getDelta();

    if ( delta && mixer)  {
        mixer.update( delta );
    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

window.onresize = function () {

    camera.aspect = windowWidth() / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( windowWidth(), window.innerHeight );

}
```

And the model: [download](https://www.mediafire.com/file/tau99gl42m6ejhj/untitled.gltf/file)
So to sum it up, I have a model with an armature that has missing properties according to three.js but are present according to blender and printing the AnimationAction and it stops any animation from running and I need to make it so this error goes away. Any help is appreciated and let me know how I can help you guys solve this. (FYI I did this on github codespaces if that helps at all)

I have tried to go back to a model that actually worked hoping it would fix and use the animation set but the same error occurs and I don't see anything wrong with this.

EDIT:
If you are having this issue too, take your code down the the mare minimum it needs to work, make that work, then add more. My problem was I added to mush to fast and lost some key parts of the code. specifically i set model = gltf.asset. Thank you to Don McCurdy for the help!

Comment: I think you want `model = gltf.scene` instead of `model = gltf.asset`. The `.asset` property is some metadata about the model, not the scene itself.

Comment: This was a typo but even after the correction it still doesn't load the animation. I am currently at school and they blocked the inspect ability so I cant check the console.

Comment: Be sure to create only one AnimationMixer, with `gltf.scene` as its parameter.  You can reuse that mixer for all animations. If you do that and are still seeing "No target node found..." then I think it'd be necessary to file a bug on three.js. But if the model looks OK on three.js-based viewers like https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ then it should work here.

Comment: I tried that, nothing changed. If there are no other solutions I might send a bug.

Comment: Just to add, I have multiple mixers so I know when every animation ends

Comment: I'd recommend reducing this to the simplest valid code you that can. Using multiple mixers, and typos with `gltf.asset`, make it hard to guess what other issues might be going on here. You can always add complexity back once you have the first animation playing. There's a working example in three.js here: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_keyframes

Comment: Thank you so much, as it turns out it was just a matter of me stripping down the code to its bare bones so it would work.

Comment: Happens to me all the time! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I added to much to fast and lost/edited some key parts of the code. Specifically I set model = gltf.asset during a debugging phase. Remember to go back to critical parts of you program and make sure they line up with the docs or what is required. Thank you to Don McCurdy for the help!